# How to pass login details from android app to 3rd party website for verification

Tags: android

I am new to programming in android using Java.Our college has their own website with details of all students, each and every student is given a Login ID and Password. 
I am making a android application for our college but my college is not willing to provide database and student info, I have made a android application with a login page which is accepting Login Id and Password from the student, is there any method like accepting login credential from the user through app and pushing it to my college website for verification, if the login is successful the app lets the user go ahead and if not prompts error ?

Comment: You need an API to do that. There should be an which accept credentials and provide you user details.
Search more about REST API and how to call it from Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this just send url of university login page.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int
                errorCode, String description, String
                                            failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(context, description, Toast
                    .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view,
                                    WebResourceRequest req,
                                    WebResourceError error) {

            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error
                    .getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl
                    ().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView then direct to university login page and check if the login is successful then direct your loginActivity to HomeActivity or something that you want.( Also you can manipulate the WebView javascript and html css if you want )

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will look into it, if you have an example of it can u share it via link